# JavaScript: chrome extension error message when dynamically creating iframe on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe

I am new to programming and am creating my first involved web application.  I have dynamically embedded iframes on button clicks and everything is working successfully but my console is littered with error messages.  I am working in a chrome browser Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: console screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is working fully and efficiently, you shouldn't be concerned.

Chrome is known for leaving in snippets of code from the development stage which crop up later on with no real benefit to the developer.

Comment: Thanks for calming my nerves.